# Iterate through ComboBox items when using CheckBox as ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, combobox

I using a ComboBox with CheckBox as ItemTemplate and I want to iterate through all items, get their checked status and write their content to a string if checked is true. The problem is that I am using a SqlDataReader to fill and bind the ComboBox from database and I can't find a way to access the items IsChecked property.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Click" Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I have tried casting the ComboBox items as CheckBoxes on the click event of them this way:

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < myComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (myComboBox.Items[i] as CheckBox);
        if (cb.IsChecked == true)
        {
            myString += "," + myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "";
        }
    }
}
```

but cb always returns NULL. I am guessing it is something with the IsChecked property binding.

I'd like to get this working but I don't want to create an object/class to fill the combobox because I need it to be filled with database. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: ah, it's been forever since i've done this, but i'm pretty sure the problem is that the control tree and the logical tree differ, so i think you have to search for the control. To make your life easier, just use databinding and make your own type and have it just set a property on your type to true.

Comment: Dont manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Handle this at the ViewModel level instead.

Comment: Don't iterate through checkboxes. Iterate through the ItemsSource of the Combobox

Comment: Shoe could you give me an example of this?

Comment: Cast as StackPanel. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (I'm not stick to MVVM pattern) and this is written on the fly :

```
 public ArrayList List { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List = new ArrayList();
            while (rdr.Read()){
                List.Add(new Class{ Id = rdr.GetString(0), Value = rdr.GetString(1), IsChecked= rdr.GetString(1) as bool}); //this class will contain the same data schema in your datareader but using properties 
            }
            rdr.Close();
            DataContext = List;
        }

  <ComboBox Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Id}" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Hichem. I didn't use your code but I got the idea. I've created a List of a class which I fill with the DataReader, then I bind that list on the ItemsSource of the ComboBox. I can now iterate through the List and get their properties as I wanted.

Comment: That was exactly the purpose.